# ZFS Raid or Hardware Raid in FreeNAS

Tags: raid, zfs, freenas

We bought SuperMicro server "SUPERMICRO CSE-826E16-R1200PB" which will be used for storage.

Total HDD

10 - 4TB Seagate HDDs
2 - 60 GB SSDs

Now im planning to install FreeNAS on it . And i will install OS on SSD which will be RAID 1 . But i have problem deciding that should i use Hardware Raid Raid6 or ZFS based RaidZ2 .

Which will be good choise Hardware Raid or ZFS Based ?

Comment: ZFS and hardware RAID often does not play well and you might lose the pool under certain circumstances. When using freenas don't use hardware RAID.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I can think of three advantages:

1. ZFS has a 'self-healing' mechanism which only works if redundancy is performed by ZFS.
2. ZFS has two tools (`zpool` and `zfs`) to manage devices, RAID, pools and filesystems from the Operating System level. This way you can easy replace devices (if they are hot swappable), manage new pools and so on.
3. ZFS allows dynamic resizing (growth) of pools when the host is running. If you decide to add drives with hardware RAID you need to do that offline. Besides, ZFS allows you to replace existing disks with larger ones (if pool is build using RAID).

Comment: All true. With one disadvantage: entire load from ZFS operations (checksums, RAID, etc) is done by processor. With dedicated RAID controller all this will happen in the processor of the controller. And IMHO ZFS in FreeNAS is not ready for enterprise :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov It's true that all operations run on the main CPU. But I haven't seen a system that is CPU bound regarding the ZFS operations. All systems I've seen have always been network or IO bound (disk).

“ZFS in FreeNAS is not ready for enterprise” → Do you have any resources backing up that claim? I've seen it successfully running in several enterprises and don't hesitate to recommend FreeNAS or TrueNAS to enterprises.

Comment: @Marco, If you check above in the questions you will see OP ask for 10 disk RAID, which IMHO can load the processor. About readiness - this is my humble opinion, the Oracle do lot of changes on ZFS after the moment FreeBSD adopt it from OpenSolaris

Comment: @Lambert So if i understand it clear. We can change the HDD in case of HDD failure (in HW Raid case) and pool will not become corrupt . And this method will work when system is offline . Am i right ?

Comment: @OmiPenguin, in most cases you can swap the HDD in case of a failing disk with hardware RAID. The controller handles a logical disk to the operating system and therefore the pool is 'unaware' of the underlying configuration. When replacing a hot swappable drive the controller is responsible for rebuilding the data onto the replaced disk. When the disks are hot swappable this will work when the system is online, taking the host offline is in that case not necessary.

Comment: @Lambert , Also one more thing Now my current RAM is 32GB. So 1) should i create L2ARC and 2) can i create L2ARC on  the same SSD which hosts Freenas OS

Comment: It depends on the workload you expect on the NAS. If a lot of users will access the same data regularly then a L2ARC cache can help. If you have unpartioned space on your SSD you can create a dedicated one for ZFS L2ARC cache, but if you do so and you have a lot of requested read IO your OS might suffer some performance degradation.